# "Unexpected any value in conditional" - happens when calling imported lib function

Tags: typescript

I have several repos that repeatedly define the same type guard, so I extracted it to a util package. These repos now have that package as a dependency and call the type guard, but a type error arises when attempting to use it. The guard is as follows:

```
function isTheThing (it: unknown): it is isTheThing {
   return it != null &&
     (it as isTheThing).type != null &&
     (it as isTheThing).type === 'what/it/should/be'
}
```

When calling the function:

```
if (!isTheThing(param)) {
  throw new Error('boooo')
}
```

This is the lint error:

```
Unexpected any value in conditional. An explicit comparison or type cast is required.eslint@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions
```

Now, if I instead define the type guard in the same file that uses it, the lint error goes away.

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Are you sure you `import`ed the file in which the type guard resides?

Comment: @pigrammer yes, the file is imported.